# Makefile behaviour related to sequence of rules to be defined

Tags: c++, makefile

I have written a  makefile in which the sequence of commands is as follows inside my makefile

```
    .PHONY: all clean distclean run
    run : $(program_NAME)
    ./$(program_NAME) > output.txt  #runs my program and stotre output in output.txt

    all: $(program_NAME)

    $(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
    $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)
```

If i change the sequence of this to below one it doesnot work for me:-

```
   .PHONY: all clean distclean run
   $(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
   $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

   all: $(program_NAME)

    run : $(program_NAME)
    ./$(program_NAME) > output.txt  #runs my program and stotre output in output.txt
```

This `doesnot generate any output.txt` for me . 
What i feel is `run :` is dependent on $(program_NAME) so `$(program_NAME): $(program_OBJS)
       $(LINK.cc) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)s` should come before `run :` in makefile. But its working fine other way round . 
       Can Someone throw some light here? (Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to observe indentation rules for makefiles. Commands to be executed by a rule should start with a tab character. Then, take into account that the first rule that appears in the makefile is executed automatically when you type `make`. In the first case the program is run. To obtain the same in the second makefile in which the `run` rule is not the first, you have to execute `make run`.

Comment: Is it always true for all makefiles that the first rule defined by them is executed automatically ?

Comment: I have taken care of indentation already in makefile i have written initially only . It was just While pasting here i did not followed the same.

Comment: Yes, the first rule is executed by default unless you specify other to `make` when executing it.